# inline svg -- getElementById not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, svg

I have inline svg and want to get some elements of this via:

```
svgdoc.getElementById( 'someid' );
```

works in Firefox, chrome, but not in Opera. There the result is `null`. 
The page (html5) is delivered as `xhtml` (content-type: application/xhtml+xml ) and the html root element contains all namespace declarations that appear in the inline-svg (svg, inkscape, ... ) which is created with inkscape and directly injected into the source.

so, the html-element looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
```

and the head of the svg which is included looks like this:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   width="581.75085"
   height="382"
   inkscape:version="0.48.3.1 r9886" >
```

the `<?xml ... ?>` declaration is removed in the html-source.

EDIT::

There is a little mistake in the explanation above... The SVG in injected into the source of the ajax response, which in turn is injected into dom via element.innerHTML. Pleas excuse this failure!

btw: `getElementsByTagName()` works.

```
console.log( svgdoc.getElementByID ) --> function getElementById(){ [native code] }
```

that is really weird, what could cause this?

Comment: My first guess would be that the namespace of the attribute is wrong (it might be `svg:id`) but I have no idea how to check that :-/

Comment: Would be nice to see the entire files, otherwise it's just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still relevant to this question but I recently found out that Opera 12 cannot getElementById() if the element to get is a SVG sub element and the SVG is not yet subchild of the DOM.

So before calling the document.getElementById() on the element with the ID which is inside a newly created SVG we must add the whole SVG to the DOM by appending it to document.body or some other container within. Then it works.